# Convert unix timestamp to human readable time in mysql

Tags: unix, timestamp, unix-timestamp, epoch

We are trying to convert unix timestamp to human readable time when running mysql commands.
For the unix date we have this working command

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(registered) AS "ResolutionDateLine" from tickets
```

which gives us an readable date like

```
2012-12-03 09:41:00
```

But we do also have unix timestamp "seconds" that we need to convert, using the same line as above we get 1970-01-01 01:00:00 but the actual value should be 89 days, 23 hours, 22 minutes and 34 seconds.

Then we tried

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(firstresponsetime, "%dd, %Hh, %Im") AS "Response" from tickets
```

with this result:

```
01d, 00h, 12m
```

Does anyone know how to convert this correctly in the mysql command?

Comment: The easiest solution is probably to implement it yourself with modulus, division and rounding.

Answer (score 2):

Your will be like

```
 select FROM_UNIXTIME(firstresponsetime, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS Response from tickets
```

or you can customize it by change second parameter.

for more please check below link:-
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Answer (score 1):

Use SEC_TO_TIME (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) to convert a duration in seconds to a HH:mm:ss notation.

select sec_to_time(3500);
results in
00:58:20